# How to get large photo URL in one API call?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, photos

I want to display large photos in my Facebook app's feed view immediately.  Is it possible to get the large photo src URL from a stream/feed using one API call?  The photo id is returned in the stream/feed and one can of course then supply this photo id in an additional FQL or graph API call to retrieve all the information about that photo.  However, is there a way using multi-query or batch calls to get a larger photo src url using one API roundtrip?

Comment: feed posts are not get, from object_id

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I haven't tried this with stream/feed photos, but the generally accepted way of doing this is:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{ID of object}/picture
```

If you want the "large" version, you would do:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{ID of object}/picture?type=large
```

I'm not 100% sure if this would work for an actual photo (instead of a user profile picture or page profile pic), but I have a hunch it will - the only caveat is that you obviously must have a logged in user that is authorized to view the photo (unless it's public).

Comment: That actually works with a few twists.  You need to use https, the type should be normal, not large, and you need an access token.  Sweet, immediate access to a larger photo:    For e.g.

https://graph.facebook.com/993589032862/picture?type=normal&access_token=192822854100507|606f7dc18352cb2ea6f0c21c.0-710381977|ZoXpprWAwfM-13-Z2qmBy_L09qM

Comment: @JohnWright: you do not need an access token for profile photo

Comment: Supported types are small, normal, large or square, not just normal as John Wright claims.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it depends on what 993589032862 is? This works: https://graph.facebook.com/993589032862/picture?type=normal but this doesn't: https://graph.facebook.com/993589032862/picture?type=large . What is 993589032862, anyway?

Comment: Wouldn't this still require you to make another call for each photo to get the high resolution imagE?

Comment: It is work for user profile image but I need posted (User's wall post) image in actual size. Because it is shows thumb size image. if any idea then please reply me.

Comment: @Pratik - A quick search-a-roo brought me to this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15069660/542550 `You can replace type=large with width=9999&height=9999 for the original size image: https://graph.facebook.com/someuser/picture?width=9999&height=9999`

Comment: @Pratik - Lucas down below said the same thing - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20194301/542550

Comment: @streetlogics - it is working for users profile picture and I am talking about image which is in user's wall post.

Comment: @Pratik - this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419144/get-picture-object-from-facebook-post-with-graph-api

Comment: None of the above currently works with the /v2.0/ endpoints  -  /v2.0/{object_id}/picture?redirect=0&height=400&type=normal&width=400 gives you a 135x135 square photo

Comment: from the new documentation -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/picture

Comment: How to get feed posts it will not get

Comment: I just tried and `?type=large` is not supported, the largest is `?type=normal`. Also not requires an access token. I currently don't need `width` and `height` to get a "reasonable" (~720px) picture but who knows...

Answer (score 31):

If anybody is looking to this and type large is not enough, I found other solutions.

Type `large` is kind of small anyway (close to 200px). You can get larger image by adding i.e. `?width=1000` or `?height=1000`. Facebook will return picture closest to given dimension and preserve aspect ratio. When passing both dimenstions like `?width=1000&height=1000`, facebook will cut image to given dimensions (in this case square).

Comment: you hero! I cannot believe I didn't think of that!!

Answer (score 2):

Use Facebook UserId (Oject ID) to get the picture.

[https://graph.facebook.com/173xxxx8635/picture?type=large&redirect=false](https://graph.facebook.com/173xxxx859658635/picture?type=large&redirect=false)

which returns JSON data with picture URL.

```
{
   "data": {
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/xxx/xyz/1cc066a2cae3f301d"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good trick with the new api is to get the pic_cover field from the event table and to process it according to the size you want to use

Answer (score 1):

I found when I was having this trouble that it turned out to be the picture I was downloading rather than the size I was setting it.

If for example I downloaded all my photos with a request of

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos?fields=created_time,name,picture&type=tagged" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection * connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    NSDictionary * userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:userData[@"data"]];

    for (NSDictionary * dict in eventsToAdd) {

        UIImage * image = dict[@"picture"] 
    }
}];
```

I am using the dictionary key search "picture" as I want the picture.

This though will get me a lower quality picture than if I searched for "source" in this search:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos?fields=created_time,name,source&type=tagged" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection * connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    NSDictionary * userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:userData[@"data"]];

    for (NSDictionary * dict in eventsToAdd) {

        UIImage * image = dict[@"source"] 
    }
}];
```

If you go on the Facebook API explorer and search for photos and then click on the picture and source jpg links you can see the difference in size and quality.

Since changing this method I have managed to get rid of using the type parameters as it doesn't seem to make a different.

Note: I am using iPhone and not iPad or a larger screen so I don't know how this affects bigger screens.

Comment: How to get picture from object_id

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @streetlogics works fine but only on pictures that have `{object_id}`.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{object_id}/picture
```

But I also wanted large pictures for the feed's shared links, which sometimes don't have `{object_id}`. I finally realized that the `{picture}` thumbnail URL contains the encoded URL for the original site's large image:

```
https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBe9UvGd0vPbAHP&w=130&h=130&url=http%3A%2F%2Fskift.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F12%2Fpollution.jpg&cfs=1
```

--> contains -->

```
http://skift.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/pollution.jpg
```

So I made a loop that checks for `{object_id}` and if not present then extracts the URL from `{picture}`:

```
if(isset($post['object_id'])) {
    echo "http://graph.facebook.com/".$post['object_id']."/picture";
    }
    elseif(isset($post['picture'])) {
        echo urldecode(preg_replace('/&cfs.*/', '', preg_replace('/.*url=/', '', $post['picture'])));
    } 
    else {
        echo "no_large_image";
}
```