# Get Facebook Profile Picture in higher resolution

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was looking for the best way to get a user profile picture with the Facebook Graph API.

Looking through the documentation, I've found this:

> You can specify the picture size you want with the type argument, which should be one of square (50x50), small (50 pixels wide, variable height), normal (100 pixels wide, variable height), and large (about 200 pixels wide, variable height)

My question is: Is there any way to get the profile picture on a higher resolution than 200px?

I've recently found this solution, but I don't know how can I check if the user has the album in another language:

```
FB.api('/me/albums', function (response)
  {
    for (album in response.data)
    {
      // Find the Profile Picture album
      if (response.data[album].name == "Profile Pictures")
      {
         // Get a list of all photos in that album.
         FB.api(response.data[album].id + "/photos", function(response)
           {
             // The image link
             image = response.data[0].images[0].source;
           });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting full-size profile picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574759/getting-full-size-profile-picture)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is straight from the documentation

> You can specify the picture size you want with the type argument,
>   which should be one of square (50x50), small (50 pixels wide, variable
>   height), normal (100 pixels wide, variable height), and large (about
>   200 pixels wide, variable height):
>
> `http://graph.facebook.com/{ID}/picture?type=large`

Now, there's nothing stopping you from calling into the graph to get larger sizes, but you have to have a valid user access token to do so.

Comment: Supposing that I've a valid access token to do the corresponding request, What's the method that I've to call to get that picture in larger sizes?

Comment: You already posted that code in your original question above on how to get the larger sizes.

Comment: I know, but also I need the best way to read the Profile Pictures album in different languages.

Comment: Ah, use the `type` field.  Check it out here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/ to see what it does.

Comment: Actually you can do what Mantas wrote (get "any" size you want), without an access token. Some profile images are however uploaded years ago where it seems they won't go beyond the size of 200px. (Discovered this because my profile picture is 8 years old and won't scale above 200px)

Comment: This should not be the answer as there are other methods to fetch higher resolution pictures that 200x200.

Answer (score 6):

You can control it by query string parameters by adding width and height:
https://graph.facebook.com/1483610454/picture?width=160&height=160
https://graph.facebook.com/1483610454/picture?width=300&height=300

Comment: This is not giving higher resolution image anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the full quality image by using the [Facebook JavaScript API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart):

```
FB.api('/{ID}?fields=picture.height(2048)', function(response){
   $("#profile_pic").attr("src",response.picture.data.url);
});
```

Assuming you have a

```
<img id="profile_pic" src=""/>
```

Somewhere in the body

Answer (score 0):

Am doing.

```
FB.api('/'+id+'/picture?type=large&width=300&height=300', function(response){
    if(response && !response.error){
        // do your stuff.
    }
})
```

You can define the `width` and `height` to any value that suits you. You will see the additional options on their documentation.