# Display mega size profile pictures facebook api php

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My app relies on very large, high quality user avatars.  The code that I am currently using is  this:

http://graph.facebook.com/USERID/picture?type=large

I get a picture, but it's about 200px by 200px

Is there a way to get the photo from the user's profile picture's album?

Comment: This is the question that answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574759/getting-full-size-profile-picture

Answer (score 0):

You can get the set of profile pics using the [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) query [select src_big from photo where aid in (select aid from album where owner = me() and type = 'profile')](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20src_big%20from%20photo%20where%20aid%20in%20%28select%20aid%20from%20album%20where%20owner%20=%20me%28%29%20and%20type%20=%20%27profile%27%29) and make an assumption that the first one is the current profile pic. It won't be foolproof however, but there's no other way to get a fullsize profile pic.