# How to get full-size profile picture in Facebook's PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How to get one's full-size profile picture in Facebook's PHP SDK? I know about the `?type=large` method, but result is only 200px wide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574759/getting-full-size-profile-picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `?type=large` is only returning a 200px wide image, then that is the largest one Facebook has.

You can scale the image larger by specifying the width and height in the query string: `?width=300&height=300` and Facebook will return a scaled-up version of the image. See [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/22/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) for more info.

The limit on this seems to be 75% larger than the size of the largest stored image Facebook has. For example, my large profile pic is ~180px. If I request a width or height > 312, I get a 312px image back.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the width and height parameters! This is probably something I need! Thanks!

Comment: They were just announced ~10 days ago. Follow the developer blog. There are new features released every week.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/YOURNAME/picture
```

Replace `YOURNAME` with name of the user you want to get the photo of.

See also:
[Facebook API - How do I get a Facebook user's profile image through the Facebook API (without requiring the user to "Allow" the application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821061/facebook-api-how-do-i-get-a-facebook-users-profile-image-through-the-fb-api)

Comment: I know about this, but the result is too small.