# FaceBook get the bigger profile image

Tags: facebook

I an using this url to get the image profile of user:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/userid/picture?type=large
```

But i noticed that i get image profile in 180*135 and i see that the image profile in my face book profile is more big then this.
It is possible to get the real image? or the large is the maximum?

Comment: Have you looked at this SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574759/getting-full-size-profile-picture

Answer (score -1):

Well, there is. You would have to create a facebook app, request access to the users picture albums, retrieve the images from the "Profile Pictures" album and scan that album for the currently used image.

If you have luck, its always the first image in the album. If not, you are in trouble and would have to do image comparsions.